# Blocking getters while async task completes

Tags: c#, reflection, getter-setter

I constantly load objects from the database. Usually I would load the object when I need it, and in the constructor I call the database and populate all the methods I need to.

What I had done to speed up this process was create a task in the constructor and use wait before I returned the value in a getter. For example

Before:

```
class Foo{

    public string Bar {get;set;}

    public Foo(int id){
        DataRow res; 
        //Do database operations
        Bar = res["Bar"].ToString()
    }  
}
```

Now:

```
class Foo{

    private Task LoadTask;

    private string _Bar;
    public string Bar {
        get {
            LoadTask.Wait();
            return _Bar;
        }
        set {
            _Bar = value;
        }
    }

    public Foo(int id){
        LoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            DataRow res; 
            //Do database operations
            Bar = res["Bar"].ToString();
        });
    } 
}
```

What I am wanting to do is extend a class, where in the constructor it fires off this task, calls an overridden method in the sub class and then block any getting of any property until the task completes.

The most I found was this, but not to sure if its what I want at all

http://www.gutgames.com/post/Overridding-a-Property-With-ReflectionEmit.aspx

Comment: Fire and forget task inside the constructor, long-running/virtual method calls inside that task, blocking access to *every* virtual property until the object is asynchronously "constructed" - this entire design seems pretty fishy.

Comment: Is there anything else that could get around this? Or just load the entire object in an async fashion and wait for that task to finish? Suggestions?

Comment: I'm not seeing a trivial solution here. You could start out by wrapping your instances of `Foo` and its derived types in `Lazy<Foo>`, kicking off the lazy initialisation asynchronously, and then using the `Value` property to block until the instance is fully loaded. It's a very rough approach though and things like exception propagation may become a pain. In an ideal world you'd have a factory type producing instances of `Foo` and its derivatives asynchronously, but you'd have to rewrite quite a bit of consuming code to make it async-friendly, which, I understand, may not always be an option.

Comment: Just for you to get an idea of what I am doing, I am refracting a few years work and improving it a long the way, so something like that isn't out of the question. What I was thinking is that every time I do a request I need to use `Foo` object along the way, at some point of time. Usually it's one of the first things to be used, but sometimes it may not be needed until the end. This could be a wide range of objects as well, not just `Foo`. So what I was wanting to do is fire of that loading of objects at the start of the request that I know 9/10 I will be using, then when its time to use it

Comment: The object will be constructed and ready to rumble. The time it takes for the property to wait for the load task to complete will always be less then what it was before because it has already started the process of loading the values before hand, it may also have already finished loading these values.

Comment: Or would I literally just be starving my threads?

Comment: What you're describing is essentially a producer-consumer pattern where the producer is pre-loading your `Foo` instances as soon as it has enough information to do so, and the consumer just grabs them when they're ready which may or may not involve blocking. In my mind this is a perfect fit for a *pipeline* (I'm quite biased here as it's one of my favourite concurrent patterns). The beauty of a pipeline is that you can dedicate as many threads as necessary to each stage rather than starting tasks willy-nilly and *hoping* that you got the number of worker threads right.

Comment: That almost fits the bill, however I am only looking for a produce once, consume as much as needed. 

Back to the real question. Is it possible to block properties while the tasks finishes, if needed?

Comment: What are the potential states of the members WRT being loaded async? Is it going to be either all members are loaded with their values, or no members are loaded with their values? If this is the case, then why make available to the caller a object that has none of its data loaded -- in the end the caller would still have to wait for the data

Comment: So rather than wait for the properties. Wait for the object. That makes sense. Please make this an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Thats Right! Otherwise you will need to synchronize access to each Property. One other thought I had on this topic is that you could change your code to react to the data as it becomes available, instead of constantly waiting for data that is not available. Thats the idea behind [reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Comment: @FabianCook, looking over the comments again you actually made the best suggestion yourself - wrap each objects initialisation in a task and then `await` it or block on its `Result` (not a big fan of this, but it sort of makes sense in this scenario) when you actually need the fully loaded `Foo` instance. That ensures that you *cannot* access the object before it is fully loaded (which is something you were trying to achieve in the first place), and you can always tweak the scheduling of each task for more fine-grained parallelisation so as not to flood the thread pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said earlier, I think this design can be improved, but I appreciated the technical challenge so I gave it a shot.

What you talked about sounded not too dissimilar to Entity Framework's dynamically created change tracking proxies, so I had a quick look around for frameworks which work with dynamic proxies and quickly settled on Castle Project (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core) as my weapon of choice.

**Naive implementation**

This is what we're going for at this stage:

```
Foo foo = Foo.Factory.Create<Foo>();

foo.Bar = "Zzz"; // Runs immediately.

string bar = foo.Bar; // Blocks until initialisation has completed.
```

Let's leave out inheritance for now (pretend that `Foo` is sealed).

We want `Foo` to have no public constructors forcing the consumer to instantiate it via `Foo.Factory.Create<Foo>()`, which returns a dynamic proxy derived from `Foo` with an additional bit of functionality injected into every virtual property getter invocation: wait for the initialisation tasks to complete.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Castle.DynamicProxy;

public class Foo
{
    // Fields.
    protected readonly List<Task> InitialisationTasks = new List<Task>();

    // Properties.
    // These have to be declared virtual
    // in order for dynamic proxying to work.
    public virtual string Bar { get; set; }

    protected Foo()
    {
        // Initialisation work.
        this.InitialisationTasks.Add(Task.Delay(500));
    }

    // Responsible for instantiating dynamic
    // proxies of Foo and its derivatives.
    public static class Factory
    {
        // Static fields.
        static readonly ProxyGenerator ProxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
        static readonly WaitForInitInterceptor Interceptor = new WaitForInitInterceptor();

        // Factory method.
        public static T Create<T>() where T : Foo
        {
            return ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy<T>(Interceptor);
        }

        class WaitForInitInterceptor : IInterceptor
        {
            public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
            {
                // Applies to getters only.
                if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("get_"))
                {
                    var foo = invocation.InvocationTarget as Foo;

                    if (foo != null)
                    {
                        // Block until initialisation completes.
                        Task.WhenAll(foo.InitialisationTasks).Wait();
                    }

                    // Continue to the target method.
                    invocation.Proceed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good, but by the sound of it we'll also have to deal with inheritance. The existing design will not support that, because:

- the derived class can introduce a public constructor thereby bypassing proxy creation via `Foo.Factory.Create<Foo>()` - we need to disallow that.
- any properties in a derived type need to declared `virtual` so that their getter invocations can be intercepted by the proxy.

**Tweaking to support inheritance**

Reflection to the rescue:

```
public class Foo
{
    // Fields.
    protected readonly List<Task> InitialisationTasks = new List<Task>();

    // Properties.
    // These have to be declared virtual
    // in order for dynamic proxying to work.
    public virtual string Bar { get; set; }

    protected Foo()
    {
        // Enforce proxy integrity.
        this.Validate();

        // Initialisation work.
        this.InitialisationTasks.Add(Task.Delay(500));
    }

    private void Validate()
    {
        var type = ProxyUtil.GetUnproxiedType(this);

        // No public constructors.
        if (type.GetConstructors().Length != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Public constructors not supported in derived types."
            );
        }

        // No non-virtual properties.
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            // We're only interested in getters.
            var method = property.GetGetMethod();

            if (method != null && !method.IsVirtual)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Only virtual properties are supported."
                );
            }
        }
    }

    // Responsible for instantiating dynamic
    // proxies of Foo and its derivatives.
    public static class Factory
    {
        // Static fields.
        static readonly ProxyGenerator ProxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
        static readonly WaitForInitInterceptor Interceptor = new WaitForInitInterceptor();

        // Factory method.
        public static T Create<T>() where T : Foo
        {
            return ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy<T>(Interceptor);
        }

        class WaitForInitInterceptor : IInterceptor
        {
            public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
            {
                // Applies to getters only.
                if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("get_"))
                {
                    var foo = invocation.InvocationTarget as Foo;

                    if (foo != null)
                    {
                        // Block until initialisation completes.
                        Task.WhenAll(foo.InitialisationTasks).Wait();
                    }

                    // Continue to the target method.
                    invocation.Proceed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if we were to create `class FooDerived : Foo` which has a public constructor or non-virtual properties (properties that don't have a getter are exempt from this rule), the base constructor will throw thereby forcing the consumer to use `Foo.Factory.Create<FooDerived>()`.

If `FooDerived` needs to perform its own asynchronous initialisation work, it can just add its own tasks to `InitialisationTasks` - any property getter will block until *all* of them have completed.

This code is a bit rough due to each 'Foo' proxy initialisation doing a lot of intensive work behind the covers (via `Validate`). In an ideal world I would have some kind of cache (perhaps a dictionary) of types which have already passed the validation, and skip the slow Reflection-bound validation for those.

**Alternative approach**

While dynamic proxies are fun, the design is flawed. The concerns are not well-separated. `Foo` shouldn't really be worrying about pulling out its own data in the first place, and definitely shouldn't be worrying about `Task`s, thread pool and the like. This was discussed extensively in the comments, and I think your best bet really is to kick off the data loading tasks at the point where you have enough information to do so, save the `Task` references (or whatever other async unit of work you're using), and then await them (or block by getting `Result` or calling `Wait`) when you need to use the fully-loaded instance. This ensures that your `Foo` instances are not accessible until the loading is fully finished and gives you reasonable control over how the async object loading is scheduled. You could, for example, roll your own limited concurrency scheduler, or use `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`s `ExclusiveScheduler` to ensure that you are not flooding the thread pool with work. Batching object loading (using `Task<IEnumerable<Foo>>` instead of `IEnumerable<Task<Foo>>`, for example) is another good way of keeping tabs on the number of tasks you create. It's easy to get creative with async loading once you decouple it from your object construction logic, and it's almost certainly the right way to go.

Comment: That's the bugger. I know of proxies in java, but couldn't remember what they were called